# Databinding function not detecting change in array of objects

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have:

```
<template is="dom-repeat"
        initial-count="1"
        index-as="index"
        items="{{uploadState}}">
  <div hidden="[[getState(index)]]" class="layout vertical center-center">
```

and I have:

```
  properties: {
    uploadState: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(1));
        var newArray = arr.map(()=> {
          return { value: false };
        });
        return newArray;
      },
      notify: true
    },
    getState: function(index) {
      var uploaded = this.get(['uploadState', index]);
      // use this.linksPath??
      return uploaded.value;
  }
```

And:

```
changeState: function(index) {
  this.uploadState[index].value = true;
}
```

When I change `this.uploadState[0].value` to false the `hidden="[[getState(index)]]"` does not detect the change.

How would I make `hidden` detect the change? I read this [similar issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2122) but not sure how I would use `linkPath` on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't work with native arrays in Polymer with data bindings. Polymer has it's own way of mapping the array elements in memory and it won't be able to detect a change to a array of elements.

Instead, I had to use the Polymer api's to mutate the arrays..`this.get` and `this.set`.  This takes some getting use to since you will need to treat array elements as paths as I did with `uploadState.*`.

Documentation is a little rough since since there is no api documentation for `array.base()`(at least that I found ....not `Polymer.base()`).

Solution:

[See Bind to an array item](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)

```
 <div hidden$="{{getState(uploadState.*, index, 'value')}}">

...

    uploadState: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(1));
        var newArray = arr.map(()=> {
          return { value: false };
        });
        return newArray;
      },
      notify: true
    }
  },
  getState: function(change, index, path) {
    var uploaded = this.get(path, change.base[index]);
    return uploaded;
  },
  changeState: function() {
    this.set('uploadState.0.value', true);
  }
```